# how can i remove the layout of an iframe

Tags: html, css

I tried inserting de `iframe` inside a `div`:

```
<div class="divIframe">
     <iframe src="~/Home/iframeView" width="100%" height="900px"></iframe>
</div>
```

And used this css:

```
.divIframe{
    overflow: hidden;
}

iframe{
    position: relative;
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;

}
```

Also used: `frameBorder="0"`

But it shows anyways the layout inside the iframe:

Index:

[image]

Iframe:

[image]

What is marked with red is the layout. What I have to do to avoid this?

what I expect for the iframe:

[image]

Comment: It is impossible to guess what you mean. Can you draw on the images to see what is wrong and post an example of how you want it to look?

Comment: Yes, i'm with that.